# bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove() ignores newly set active_material_index on provided object and throws blenkernel error

Tags: python, materials, operator, custom-properties

I'm Working on a material management panel
the issue I'm facing is, as seen in the code below the active_material_index is set and used to select and remove the relative slot but both select and remove completely ignore the set index and instead try to access indexes out of range or that never existed

although the console says to report it as a bug the same code as standalone material remover does not cause the error so i believe it should not be reported, as it's likely caused by both functions not liking the way the index is set

due to the fact that slots cannot be accessed directly anymore like how materials can be accessed, is there any other possible way of altering material slots on an object in a direct way that allows a specific index to be passed?

indexes are correctly reflected in the UI and seems like only those two function are ignoring it, as other functions that are not self-sufficent work correctly

Works fine with one object but as soon as there are multiple object with the material being removed as a slot, it stops completely to work

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Context
from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty, FloatProperty, BoolProperty, CollectionProperty, PointerProperty

### Alx Material Property Groups
class Alx_Material(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    def GetMaterialName(self):
        return self.material.name
    
    name : StringProperty()
    material_name : StringProperty(get=GetMaterialName)
    material : PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Material)

class Alx_MaterialCollection(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name : StringProperty()
    pass

def AlxMaterialAssignFromScene(self):
    for Material in bpy.data.materials:
        if (Material is not None) and (bpy.context.scene.alx_materials.find(Material.name) == -1):
            AlxMaterial = bpy.context.scene.alx_materials.add()
            AlxMaterial.name = Material.name
            AlxMaterial.material = Material

### Alx Material Operators
class Alx_OT_MaterialRegisterChanges(bpy.types.Operator):
    """"""

    bl_label = ""
    bl_idname = "alx.material_register_changes"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        AlxMaterialAssignFromScene(self)
        
        for AlxMaterial in bpy.context.scene.alx_materials:
            if (AlxMaterial.name not in bpy.data.materials):
                NewMaterial = bpy.data.materials.new(AlxMaterial.name)
                NewMaterial = AlxMaterial
        return {"FINISHED"}

class Alx_OT_MaterialAppendToScene(bpy.types.Operator):
    """"""

    bl_label = ""
    bl_idname = "alx.material_append_to_scene"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True
    
    def execute(self, context: Context):
        bpy.data.materials.new("Material")

        return {"FINISHED"}

class Alx_OT_MaterialRemoveFromScene(bpy.types.Operator):
    """"""

    bl_label = ""
    bl_idname = "alx.material_remove_from_scene"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        if (len(bpy.context.scene.alx_materials) != 0) and (bpy.context.scene.alx_active_material_index < len(bpy.context.scene.alx_materials)):
            MaterialID = bpy.data.materials.get(bpy.context.scene.alx_materials[bpy.context.scene.alx_active_material_index].name)

            MaterialUserMap = bpy.data.user_map(key_types={"MATERIAL"}, value_types={"MESH"})
            MaterialUsers = MaterialUserMap.get(bpy.data.materials[MaterialID.name], None)

            for User in MaterialUsers:
                MaterialUser = User
                if (MaterialUser.name not in ["Scene", "Airbrush"]):
                    MeshUserMap = bpy.data.user_map(key_types={"MESH"}, value_types={"OBJECT"})
                    MeshUsers = MeshUserMap.get(bpy.data.meshes[MaterialUser.name], None)

                    for MeshUser in MeshUsers:
                        print(MeshUsers)
                        MeshUser.active_material_index = MeshUser.material_slots.find(bpy.context.scene.alx_materials[bpy.context.scene.alx_active_material_index].name)
                        print(MeshUser)
                        print(MeshUser.active_material_index)
                        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_select()
                        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()     

            if ((bpy.context.scene.alx_active_material_index -1) != -1):
                bpy.context.scene.alx_active_material_index = bpy.context.scene.alx_active_material_index - 1

        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class Alx_OT_MaterialAssignToSelection(bpy.types.Operator):
    """"""

    bl_label = ""
    bl_idname = "alx.material_assign_to_selection"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        for Object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if (Object.type == "MESH"):
                if (len(bpy.context.scene.alx_materials) != 0) and (bpy.context.scene.alx_active_material_index < len(bpy.context.scene.alx_materials)):
                    if bpy.context.scene.alx_materials[bpy.context.scene.alx_active_material_index].name not in Object.data.materials:
                        Object.data.materials.append(bpy.context.scene.alx_materials[bpy.context.scene.alx_active_material_index].material)

        return {"FINISHED"}

### Alx Material UI
class Alx_UL_MaterialSlotList(bpy.types.UIList):
    bl_idname = "alx.material_slot_list"

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):

        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            layout.prop(item, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=icon)

class Alx_PT_MaterialSlotSelector(bpy.types.Panel):
    """"""

    bl_label = ""
    bl_idname = "alx.material_slot_selector"

    bl_category = "Alx 3D"

    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
            return True

    def draw(self, context):
        AlxLayout = self.layout

        MaterialOutlinerRow = AlxLayout.row(align=True)
        
        
        SM_ToolsColumn = MaterialOutlinerRow.column()
        SM_ToolsColumn.operator(Alx_OT_MaterialAppendToScene.bl_idname, text="", icon="ADD") 
        SM_ToolsColumn.operator(Alx_OT_MaterialRemoveFromScene.bl_idname, text="", icon="FAKE_USER_OFF")

        SceneMaterialColumn = MaterialOutlinerRow.column()
        SceneMaterialColumn.template_list(listtype_name=Alx_UL_MaterialSlotList.bl_idname, list_id="", dataptr=bpy.context.scene, propname="alx_materials", active_dataptr=bpy.context.scene, active_propname="alx_active_material_index")
        
        
        SM_ToolsColumn.operator(Alx_OT_MaterialRegisterChanges.bl_idname, text="", icon="FILE_REFRESH")
        
        
        SM_ToolsColumn.label(icon="RIGHTARROW")

        SceneMaterialColumn.operator(Alx_OT_MaterialAssignToSelection.bl_idname, text="Assign Material To Selection")

        MaterialCollectionColumn = MaterialOutlinerRow.column()

        MaterialCollectionColumn.template_list(listtype_name=Alx_UL_MaterialSlotList.bl_idname, list_id="", dataptr=bpy.context.scene, propname="alx_material_collection_library", active_dataptr=bpy.context.scene, active_propname="alx_active_material_index")
        
        MC_ToolsColumn = MaterialOutlinerRow.column()

        MaterialCollectionColumn.label(text="Operator Here")
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
AlxClassQueue = [
        Alx_Material,
        Alx_MaterialCollection,

        Alx_OT_MaterialRegisterChanges,
        Alx_OT_MaterialAssignToSelection,
        Alx_OT_MaterialAppendToScene,
        Alx_OT_MaterialRemoveFromScene,

        
        Alx_UL_MaterialSlotList,
        Alx_PT_MaterialSlotSelector
        ]
                
                
                
def register():
    print("AlxOverHaul Registering...")
    for AlxQCls in AlxClassQueue:
        bpy.utils.register_class(AlxQCls)

    bpy.types.Scene.alx_materials = CollectionProperty(type=Alx_Material)
    bpy.types.Scene.alx_active_material_index = IntProperty()
    bpy.types.Scene.alx_material_collection_library = CollectionProperty(type=Alx_MaterialCollection)

    #bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(AlxMaterialRegisterChanges)
    #bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(key=(bpy.types.Object, "material_slots"), owner="owner", args=(), notify=AlxMaterialRegisterChanges)

    print("AlxOverHaul Registered:")
    print(AlxClassQueue)

def unregister():
    print("AlxOverHaul Un-Registering...")
    for AlxQCls in AlxClassQueue:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(AlxQCls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.alx_materials
    del bpy.types.Scene.alx_active_material_index

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

ERROR (bke.material): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v400\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\material.cc:1287 BKE_object_material_slot_remove: invalid material index 0, report a bug!

Comment: It's better if you provide a [minimal, complete, reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can easily be copy-pasted so we can directly run your code to test. Your current sample does not meet this requirement as it's not complete.

Comment: i can update  the code, but as i said even a just the material code is a lot and i might run out of characters, i'll post a link in case it doesn't fit